# Fill a ListView from Postgres Database in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I'm using WPF C# Visual Studio 2012. I have a Listview in my xaml like:

```
<ListView 
    Name="listview" 
    Grid.Column="0"                
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="15"
    Margin="5"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Background="WhiteSmoke">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn 
                    Header="column1" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path}" />
                <!--other path-->
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The code behind to fill this Listview (in xaml.cs):

```
NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server = " + myModule.Server + ";Port = " + myModule.Port + ";User ID = " + myModule.UserID + ";Password = " + myModule.Password + ";Database = " + myModule.Database);
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from tblstudents_secure order by stud_id ASC", connection);

command.Connection = connection;
NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);


DataSet ds=new DataSet ();
adapter.Fill(ds);
listview.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

When I run my program, I know that it fills the listview because I can see it's rows when I hover my mouse on that, but I cannot see any text on those rows!

What did I miss?

Comment: is "Path" a property/columc of the data ? DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this solution:

In my XAML:

```
<ListView 
    Margin="10" 
    Name="lvDataBinding">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Student Number" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding list_studid}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding list_studfname}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Middle Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding list_studmname}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding list_studlname}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In my xaml.cs:

```
public class User
{
    public string list_studid { get; set; }
    public string list_studfname { get; set; }
    public string list_studmname { get; set; }
    public string list_studlname { get; set; }
}


public void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NpgsqlConnection iConnect = new NpgsqlConnection
                                    ("Server = " + myModule.Server + ";
                                      Port = " + myModule.Port + ";
                                      User ID = " + myModule.UserID + ";
                                      Password = " + myModule.Password + ";
                                      Database = " + myModule.Database);
    iConnect.Open();
    NpgsqlCommand iQuery = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from tblstudents_secure", iConnect);
    iQuery.Connection = iConnect;
    NpgsqlDataAdapter iAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(iQuery);

    DataSet iDataSet = new DataSet();
    iAdapter.Fill(iDataSet, "LIST");
    
    int lstCount = iDataSet.Tables["LIST"].Rows.Count;//lstCount holds the total count of the list from database

    int i = 0;//used as counter
    List<User> items = new List<User>();
    while (lstCount > i)
    {

        items.Add(new User()
        {
            list_studid = iDataSet.Tables["LIST"].Rows[i]["stud_id"].ToString(),
            list_studfname = iDataSet.Tables["LIST"].Rows[i]["stud_fname"].ToString(),
            list_studmname = iDataSet.Tables["LIST"].Rows[i]["stud_mname"].ToString(),
            list_studlname = iDataSet.Tables["LIST"].Rows[i]["stud_lname"].ToString()
        });

        lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;//lvDataBinding is the name of my ListView

        i++;
    }
}
```

#### Explanation:

In my design (XAML), the `DisplayMemberBinding` property of the `GridViewColumn` holds the Binding List, which from code behind is `list_studid, list_studfname, list_studmname, list_studlname`. Now, we have a "catcher" on our design, we set the "thrower" from our code behind.

The `public class User` holds and initializes the binding list – `list_studid`, `list_studfname`, etc.

Upon user `CLICK` on my button (`cmdSearch`), we call the database, open it, perform select query, fill it into the dataset, and loop until the end of the list.

Now the "thrower" starts on the loop, including the `List<User> items = new List<User>();` . While looping, the `list_studid`, etc. holds the data from the database `(list_studid = iDataSet.Tables["LIST"].Rows[i]["stud_id"].ToString())` and converts it to string (`.ToString()`).

Then we "throw" it to the listview in `lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;`. And as I have said, the design (XAML) "catches" this "throw", and loads it to the listview.

Comment: For anyone having a:
This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid Items.Count:5' with name '(unnamed)' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection. The following differences were detected: Accumulated count 4 is different from actual count 5. [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

Add this code after While iteration is done.
**'lvDataBinding.Items.Refresh();**

Answer (score 0):

Well It's hard to help you with this little information about your entities...
But I would bet the entities in your DB dont have a `path` property.

This example worked for me:

```
   <ListView 
            Name="listview" 
            Grid.Column="0"                
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="15"
            Margin="5"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn 
                            Header="column1" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}" />
                    <!--other path-->
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

CodeBehind:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
    public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       var bla = new ObservableCollection<Car>()
       {
          new Car()
       };

       listview.ItemsSource = bla;
   }
 }

 public class Car
 {
   public Car()
  {
     Path = "bla";
  }
   public string Path { get; set; }
 }
```

notice the Property `Path` on my `Car` class and the line
`DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path}"` in the view.

regards