# XAML separating listview into different columns

Tags: listview

I have connected to the Postgres SQL server and retrieved data from the database sucessfully. I am putting the data to a listview to show all the columns and rows. I have done much research about separate the listview into different columns like the link below.

[Fill a ListView from Postgres Database in WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084599/fill-a-listview-from-postgres-database-in-wpf-c-sharp)

```xml
<ListView 
    Margin="10" 
    x:Name="lvDataBinding">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First name"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Last name"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Email"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

However, Visual Studio 2019 said I have the following errors.

For ListView.View:

Error: The attachable property "View" was not found in type "ListView"

For GridView:

Error: The type "GridView" was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

For GridViewColumn:

Error: The type "GridViewColumn" was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please don't use image, put the error messages as text in your question.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please help me?